# Feedforward Neural Network backpropagation problems

Tags: javascript, typescript, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to build my own little neural network library.

Everytime I run my code, it builds a new network with random weights.
Then I train it like 20,000 times:

```
const trainingData = [
  {
    data: [0,1],
    target: [1]
  },
  {
    data: [1,0],
    target: [1]
  },
  {
    data: [1,1],
    target: [0]
  },
  {
    data: [0,0],
    target: [0]
  }
]

const nn = new FNN(2,6,12,6,1)

for(let i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
  nn.train(trainingData[index].data, trainingData[index].target)
}

console.log(nn.query([0,1]))
console.log(nn.query([1,0]))
console.log(nn.query([0,0]))
console.log(nn.query([1,1]))
```

As you can see I'm trying to solve the XOR problem with 4/5 layer (I know it's a bit overkill).
But when I run my code a couple of times the outputs are sometimes wrong:

```
$ deno run sketch.ts 
[ 0.9808040222512294 ]
[ 0.9808219014520584 ]
[ 0.009098634709446591 ]
[ 0.009259505045600065 ]

$ deno run sketch.ts 
[ 0.984698425823075 ]
[ 0.9844728486048201 ]
[ 0.010107497773167363 ]
[ 0.010367109588917735 ]

$ deno run sketch.ts 
[ 0.9856540170897103 ]
[ 0.5163204342937323 ] <-- this should be 1
[ 0.02873017555538064 ]
[ 0.516320908619891 ] <-- this should be 0
```

What could be the problem here?
Is it because of the random weights?
It's interesting, that the wrong outputs are always really close to each other.

I'm using the sigmoid function and a learning rate of 0.2.
The random weights are between -1 and 1 (Math.random() * 2 - 1)

Comment: There should be a "Hey!" at the beginning of the post :-)

Comment: You can always edit your own posts, but a "Hey" has no place here - questions are supposed to be concise and to the point without conversational elements.